# Ecvel VBA Error 1004 when write a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write in a cell of an excel sheet.
the way in which proceed is the following:

```
Dim sh_work As Worksheet
Set sh_work = currFileCreated.Sheets(1)
sh_work.Cells(26, 4) = "bla bla bla"
```

This works perfectly, with the exception of the cells on column "DI".
When i write:

```
Dim sh_work As Worksheet
Set sh_work = currFileCreated.Sheets(1)
sh_work.Cells(15, 113) = "bla bla bla"
```

or

```
Dim sh_work As Worksheet
Set sh_work = currFileCreated.Sheets(1)
sh_work.Range("DI15") = "bla bla bla"
```

or

```
Dim sh_work As Worksheet
Set sh_work = currFileCreated.Sheets(1)
sh_work.Range("DI15").Value = "bla bla bla"
```

error 1004 is launched

I've looked everywhere.... but nothing
can someone please tell me a solution?

Comment: Is it possible that `Sheets(1)` is a Chart sheet, not a worksheet?  Try using `Set sh_Work = currFileCreated.Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: Is that cell locked and the sheet protected?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you unprotect the worksheet?

```
Dim sh_work As Worksheet
Set sh_work = currFileCreated.Sheets(1)
sh_work.unprotect
sh_work.Cells(15, 113) = "bla bla bla"
sh_work.protect
```